# Wix Installer welcome dialog smaller text

Tags: wix, installation

I am creating a WiX installer for a project. On the welcome dialog of my MSI installer I have too much text which doesn't fit the dialog.

I have already tried to change the font and make it smaller, but with no luck.

Is there any other way I can fit the text into the welcome dialog? Either make font size smaller somehow or increase the size of the dialog. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose editing the text is out of the question? Seriously, if you have too much text to comfortably fit on the dialog, do you really think that all of the text belongs on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in dialogs are built exactly the same way that you can build in your own project.

You could copy the [WelcomeDlg](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WelcomeDlg.wxs) code into your own project, give it a new Id, then make whatever modifications you want to it. Then fix up the Back/Next buttons on neighboring dialogs so they end up at your dialog instead of the built-in ones.

```
<UI Id="MyUI">
    <!-- Start with a default UI -->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

    <!-- Create my own dialog -->
    <Dialog Id="MyWelcomeDlg" Width="XXX" Height="YYY" ...> ... </Dialog>

    <!-- Fix up the back/next buttons -->
    <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    ...
</UI>

<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="MyWelcomeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```